# Katzer email plugin is not working in Cordova - IOS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, email

I am building a hybrid application using `Cordova` and I am stuck at an email functionality. I am using Katzer email plugin from here https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.

> cordova.plugins.email.open({                  });

This functionality is working fine on my android device and when I tested it in IOS it's not working at all. No error is throwing from the application.

I am using Cordova version 5.4 and my IOS version is IOS 8.

What is wrong here?. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note:** Will downgrading the version of Cordova helps?

Comment: Inspect the app on desktop safari so you can see the errors you are getting

Answer (score 2):

Cordova iOS 4.0.0 has some significant changes, please read this blogpost from Cordova:

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/12/08/cordova-ios-4.0.0.html

That means, that you should be careful by using plugins, which are older then 08 Dec 2015.

If you make a downgrade, than you should call

> cordova clean

That will cleanup project from build artifacts.

Comment: He is not using cordova ios 4.0.0 (or at least he didn't mention it). If he is using cordova CLI 5.4, he is getting cordova ios 3.9.2, and the plugin has not been updated recently, so that's not the problem.